# How to pass array from one method to other?

Tags: java

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
List<char[]> figure = new ArrayList<char[]>();

while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    figure.add(inFile.nextLine().toCharArray());
}

inFile.close();
char[][] wholeData = figure.toArray(new char[0][]);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(wholeData));
```

There is a method that reads a txt file and puts the data into a char array.

I would like to ask if there is a way to pass the char array to another method?

Comment: of course, write a method that takes an array as argument

Comment: Did you gothrough any reference before posting this question?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a method which takes an array as the argument:

```
public void XYZ(char[] array)
{
// Do something
}
```